# node package for file attachments and image resizing

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a node package that handles file attachments and image resizing. Something similar to the paperclip and carrierwave gems.

Comment: File attachments, to e-mails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you search the [Node Modules Wiki Page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules)?  I searched for "upload" and found 2 candidates.

https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

https://github.com/rootslab/formaline

For image resizing, [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) or [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) will probably suffice.

Comment: [cloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm) is pretty cool option for people looking for cloud storage

Answer (score 3):

For image upload and resize, you can check [papercut](https://github.com/Rafe/papercut),
which is simular to carrierwave.