# Docpad design considerations

Tags: docpad

I'm coming from a php/mysql background. I'm most familiar with the Kohana PHP framework and I'm trying to learn Docpad. I have a loose understand at this point and I've built out my first website and blog. Static content makes a lot of sense to me on Docpad.

I'm working on my photography site where I want to be able to upload new images to a portfolio. The backend needs to handle an uploaded high-resolution image and create several different copies at different resolutions of the image. **My biggest question is how do I keep track of the image meta data that I want to display?** Do I generate a physical file for each image that has all the particulars I want to track and use those files as my searchable database, much like how blog posts are setup?

Or should I go the route of using something like MongoDB to store image data there where it can be queried and plugged into a layout?

Regarding handling POST or GET data, should I be reading up on the express.js docs? I'm not really sure where to turn for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses TimThumb to re-size it's images: [How does WordPress.com resize images dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475884/how-does-wordpress-com-resize-images-dynamically)

Then there is this re-sizing library for node: [node package for file attachments and image resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141720/node-package-for-file-attachments-and-image-resizing)

If you wanted to created like 3 different image sizes and use the backbone collection in DocPad, then you'd add your different re-sized images to those three different collections/folders. For access the images you might just be able to do it via it's file name. So when you copy, re-size and rename the image, in the rename step, concat the image size at the end, like: coolPhoto-med.jpg and then you could just do hard links to get to the image like /spring-collection/med/coolPhoto-med.jpg or you could use query engine  to access them.

The file model has a meta attribute: https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/master/src/lib/models/file.coffee#L17
I've yet to learn how to use it yet though.

I know we chatted yesterday on #docpad IRC but I just wanted to answer you here too. If you do code something that re-sizes images for DocPad, please do consider putting it up on Github to share with the community.

Comment: Thanks @Mikeumus, This has pointed me in the right direction. I'll definitely contribute what I come up with.